# VideoJS settimeout when the video end

Tags: video.js

I want to autoclose (settimeout) an iframe which displays a video with delay 5 sec when the video ends and only if the user click play, if not I want to autoclose the iframe after 5 sec.

How can I do this using videojs?

I've tried `setTimeout(function (), 5000);` but it's not working.
Thanks

Comment: Are you calling setTimeout on video end callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add setTimeout on ended event ?

```
 player.on('ended', function() {
        alert('video is done!');            
        setTimeout(function (), 5000);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Great i think its ok, but the condition to autoclose after 5 sec if the user does not click to play, is that possible?